# Excel: Extract a project number from a text string (various position and length)

Tags: microsoft-excel, string, string-manipulation

In an Excel spreadsheet I have a column of mixed text strings containing project master data (type, project no., address, theme and such). From this string I need to extract the project number in an automated way. One problem is that the number is situated different places in the string. That makes it difficult to use =MID() I guess. Another problem is that the number varies in length.

An example of 3 strings:

invoice no2014-0406-1 Main Street, John Nelson, purchase
tax projno 2015-0021 rejection application
gl oldroad 10 case 2014-0306-003 HUKO, JFR

From the strings I need to extract:

2014-0406-1
2015-0021
2014-0306-003

I hope this can be done automatic. Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this can actually be a bit tough when the string you are interested in can be directly attached to text as per your 1st example. If that is not the case at the very end of the project numbers and they always end with a space, and you are OK with a solution that takes into account project numbers from the 2000's onwards, you could try:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("20??-",A1),FIND(" ",A1,SEARCH("20??-",A1))-SEARCH("20??-",A1))
```

Note that this can be simplified with Microsoft365 to:

```
=LET(X,SEARCH("20??-",A1),MID(A1,X,FIND(" ",A1,X)-X))
```

If this is to simplified and you can have edge cases like: "test-test test2014-0406-5test 2020", you could try:

```
=@LET(X,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),FILTERXML("<t><s>"&CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(X,"0123456789-")),X,"</s><s>"))&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., '-')][translate(.,'-','')*0=0]"))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Note that you could also resort to regular expressions, but this requires you to use VBA. Maybe the following UDF will do:

```
Function GetProjectID(str As String, pat As String) As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = pat
    If .Test(str) Then GetProjectID = .Execute(str)(0)
End With

End Function
```

Call as `=GetProjectID(A1,"\d+-\d+(?:-\d+)*")`

Comment: Thank you very much for quick and detailed response! Yes, the number-string can have text directly attached to it. The two criteria you mention (" " after project number and only numbers with 20??) are met for most of the cases, so your first solution works perfectly. Some strings end with the project number. Hence, they have no ending " ". However, this is so few that I will extract them manually.

Comment: You could concatenate an extra space at the end `=MID(A1,SEARCH("20??-",A1),FIND(" ",A1&" ",SEARCH("20??-",A1))-SEARCH("20??-",A1))` @aliaz. Glad it helped.